# Through the bases

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

## Through the bases

In this challenge, you will be taking a number through all the bases of the rainbow

Given an input, `n`, you will output `n` in every base from 9 to 2, and back up to 9. That's `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

**Example:**

```
>>> 16
17
20
22
24
31
100
121
10000
121
100
31
24
22
20
17
```

**Rules:**

- You input can be a string or a number.
- Your output may be separated by new lines, spaces, commas, or tabs.
- You may use built in functions.
- Shortest code wins!

Comment: Can the output be comma-separated?

Comment: @vihan1086 yes.

Comment: I'm really late on this but can each line be surrounded by quotes? e.g. ``"17"\n"20"``

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, 14 bytes

```
riF,f{7-z2+bN}
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=riF%2Cf%7B7-z2%2BbN%7D&input=16).

#### How it works

```
ri             e# Read an integer I from STDIN.
  F,           e# Push [0 ... 14].
    f{       } e# For each B in that range, push I and B; then:
      7-z2+    e#   Compute abs(B - 7) + 2.
               e#   This maps [0 ... 14] to [9 ... 2 ... 9].
           b   e#   Perform base conversion.
            N  e#   Push a linefeed.
```

Comment: Just when I thought I had a chance at winning with Pyth. :P

Comment: @AlexA. I'm here to save your hope!

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
V+_Jr2TtJjkjQN
```

Needs more work, most code is spent generating 9..2..9.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Dennis and 1 thanks to Jakube!

```
V+r9 1r3TjkjQN
```

Explanation:

```
V                     For N in
 +r9 1r3T             the list [9,8,...3,2,3,...,8,9],
           jQN        convert the input to base N (returns a list),
         jk           join the list into a string, implicitly printed.
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%2Br9+1r3TjkjQN&input=5&debug=0).

Comment: `""` is just `k`, `p` already appends a linefeed and printing is implicit anyway, so `FN+r9 1r3TjkjQN` is 3 bytes shorter and looks a bit better.

Comment: @Dennis You're the man.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 59

```haskell
0%_=0
k%b=div k b%b*10+mod k b
g n=map(n%)$[9,8..3]++[2..9]
```

First, recursively defines a binary operator `%` to do base conversion, representing the output as a decimal number rather than a string. The function `g` converts the input `n` to each base from 9 to 2 and back up.

There's probably a shorter approach, advice is welcome. Saved 2 chars on parens thanks to nimi.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does `[9,8...3]` work but `[9..3]` doesn't? (the latter seems to return an empty list)

Comment: @Sp3000 It defaults to a step size of +1, so `[9..3]` is empty because `9>3`. Putting the second terms fixes the step size. It general, you can do `range(a,b,s)` as `[a,a+s..b]`.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + dc, 27

```
echo {{9..2},{3..9}}o$1p|dc
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `echo {{9..2},{3..9}}o$1p|dc`

Comment: @Dennis very good - I didn't know brace expansions could be nested like that!

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 43 bytes

```matlab
n->for i=[9:-1:2,3:9] println(base(i,n))end
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts and integer and prints to STDOUT on separate lines. The `base` function takes two integers: a base (`i`) and a number (`n`) and returns the string representation of the number in the given base. Here we just loop through the required bases and print.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```js
f=n=>[...`987654323456789`].map(v=>n.toString(v)).join` `
```

### CoffeeScript, 57 bytes

Different approach:

```coffee
f=(n)->[-7..7].map((v)->n.toString 2+Math.abs v).join ' '
```

### JavaScript (ES5), 97 bytes

```js
function f(n){return'987654323456789'.split('').map(function(v){return n.toString(v)}).join(' ')}
```

#### Demo

```js
function f(n) {
  return '987654323456789'.split('').map(function(v) {
    return n.toString(v)
  }).join(' ')
}

document.body.innerHTML = f(16)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 79

```python
g=lambda b,k=input():k and g(b,k/b)*10+k%b
c=7;exec"print g(abs(c)+2);c-=1;"*15
```

The function `g` converts a number `k` to a base `b`. We can take `k` as the program input because Python initializes default arguments when the function is defined, not each time it's called. We get the desired sequence of bases by taking the range `[-7, -6, ..., 6, 7]`, taking the absolute value, and adding 2.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript SpiderMonkey 31 (1.8), 47 bytes

```
n=>[for(i of`987654323456789`)n.toString(i)]+''
```

It doesn't get simpler than this.

Comment: Nice, but array comprehensions [have been dropped](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2856) from ES7.

Comment: @Chiru Hm, I'll update it

Answer (score 1):

## Pip, 14 = 13 + 1 bytes

Uses the `-n` flag.

```
aTB2+AB(-7,8)
```

[GitHub repository for Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)

Takes the number as a command-line argument.

```
        -7,8   Range containing integers from -7 through 7
     AB(    )  Absolute value of each
   2+          Add 2 to each
aTB            Convert command-line arg to each base
               Print resulting list, newline-separated (-n flag)
```

It's amazing how all the golfing languages are getting the same score here.

Comment: Those list formatting switches look really useful.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, the main reason I thought of them was so I wouldn't have to wrap the whole program in `(...)Jn` (4 bytes vs. 1 with `-n`) when the program consisted of a map expression (parentheses needed since `M`ap is lower precedence than `J`oin).

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES5), <s>69</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```js
function f(o){for(i=15;i--;)console.log(o.toString(i>7?i-5:9-i))}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 44 bytes

```
a=->n{(0..14).map{|j|p n.to_s((j-7).abs+2)}}
```

Call the lambda with `a.call(number)`. This prints out with quotes around each line because `p` is shorter than `puts`. I'm assuming this is allowed.

Comment: but `n=ARGV[0].to_i;(0..14).map{|j|puts n.to_s((j-7).abs+2)}` is 56 bytes and is complete (could be 54 if used `p` instead of `puts`

Comment: Oh, gotcha, thanks, I'll fix that. Edit: Fixed. Also, defining a function is slightly shorter than getting the parameters passed to the code @rdnewman

Comment: But not sure that requiring `a.call(number)` in IRB would be considered a complete program by others.  If it is, then I'd agree with you.   Actually, might be able to just do `(0..14)map{|j|p ARGV[0]((j-7).abs+2)}` and remove the `n` altogether (didn't test).

Comment: @rdnewman I saw a lambda solution like this on an answer with 6 upvotes [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54233/26724) so I assumed it was ok. In fact, they didn't even assign it to a variable and just put ``->s``..

Comment: Ah, ok.  Here's the corrected version of the last one I tried: `(0..14).map{|j|p ARGV[0].to_i.to_s((j-7).abs+2)}`; will run, but 48 bytes to your 44, so if they'll accept it, yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 52 bytes

I'll admit, this could use more golfing.

```
{n←⍵⋄⊃{⍺,' ',⍵}/{⊃,/⍕¨(~∧\0=e)/e←(10⍴⍵)⊤n}¨2+|8-⍨⍳15}
```

it is limited to at most 10 digits output

suggestions for improvement welcome

output for 16 looks like

```
17 20 22 24 31 100 121 10000 121 100 31 24 22 20 17
```